# Wi-Fi device not ready frequent error

Tags: wireless

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my system. I frequently get "Wi-Fi device not ready" error in Network Manager.

When I run the following command:

> sudo service network-manager restart

The Wi-Fi starts again. But after some time, it disconnects again with the same error. This is very frequent. Please provide a solution to this problem.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 combo HMC
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6   edited the question

Comment: I am facing the same problem but in Kali bang

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar experience, after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I had wicd running as a background process, so I ended the process it.  I used System Monitor to do this.

Note, System Monitor might only show you processes running on your home account on Ubuntu (i.e. 'my processes').

Be sure to ALSO end the 'wicd' and 'wicd-monitor' processes that are running in 'All Processes' not just from 'My Processes'.

To switch to 'All Processes', on the 'Processes' tab within System Monitor, at the top right-hand corner, select 'All Processes', the default is usually 'My Processes'.  Other items on the menu drop-down include: 'Active Processes', 'All Processes', Refresh, Show Dependencies; be sure to select 'All Processes'.

Note: you might need to repeat this process if you restart your computer.

Another option is to uninstall wicd from your completely.

Comment: Caveat: This assumes you have 'wicd' installed on your computer.